# Active admin layout was lost after overriding Controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

My new controller action:

```
controller do
  layout 'active_admin'
  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end
end
```

After refresh the page i received:

```
undefined method `base' for nil:NilClass 
render view_factory.layout
```

What should I do for fixing this?

I start rewriting controller action because i received this message for my index action:

```
undefined method `num_pages' for #<Array:0x0000000b860eb0>
render renderer_for(:index)
```

Maybe anyone know how fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial `undefined method 'num_pages' for #<Array:0x0000000b860eb0>` may be occurring if you have an instance variable set in a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` with the plural name of a model as I did. The bug is reported [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/511).

Answer (score 1):

Would need to see the code on the view page for this but it sounds to me like you are making a call for `num_pages` on an object that is an `array` class.  Since Ruby's array class has no `num_pages` method, it is throwing an error.

Comment: I did not change the view code, it is standard active_admin index view for model. Maybe I should change object class form array to smth that supports num_pages method?

Answer (score 1):

Jamie you are right! But then i received this message for my index action:

```
undefined local variable or method `per' for ActiveRecord::Relation
```

And I fix this problem by doing this:

```
# config/initializers/will_paginate.rb
if defined?(WillPaginate)
  module WillPaginate
    module ActiveRecord
      module RelationMethods
        alias_method :per, :per_page
        alias_method :num_pages, :total_pages
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The bug is reported [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/174).